# How can I let the controller know which button was clicked? [Angular/bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a button group, each button corresponding to a [playing card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card).

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button ng-repeat="card in cards" type="submit" class="btn btn-default card">{{card.rank}} {{card.suit}}</button>
</div>
```

What I want is when a button is clicked, it calls the controller's `play()` and also letting it know which card corresponds to the clicked button. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the corresponding card as a parameter with the `ng-click`

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button ng-repeat="card in cards" type="submit" ng-click="play(card)" class="btn btn-default card">{{card.rank}} {{card.suit}}</button>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $scope.play = function (card) {
            console.log(card.id);
        };
```

Comment: generally more useful to pass whole object in ... easier to use to index in arrays or modify object or whatever needs doing with it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would not make the button `type="submit"`, because that will not give you the control you need, so remove that attribute. Then, add an `ng-click="play(card); $event.preventDefault()"` attribute so it calls the `play()` method on the controller, passing in the card, and also prevents the default browser behaviour for clicking buttons, which is usually to submit the form.